# Error while using un-initialized variable in an expression in a template file

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I am trying to process a template file using template-toolkit version 2.29 and perl 5.28.1. I am getting below warning while processing template file 
**Argument "" isn't numeric in addition (+) at  line xyz** 
 
I think it is because in the template file we have un-initialized variables which are used in an arithmetic expression. 
 
**Is it necessary to initialize a variable before using it in an expression if using template-toolkit version 2.29?**
In the below code the warning occurs for line 5.

Below is the snippet from code.

```
[%- groups = {} -%] <br/>
[%- cols = [ 10, 10, 20, 30 ] -%] <br/>
[%- FOREACH c IN cols -%] <br/>
   [%- val = c -%] <br/>
   [%- groups.$val = groups.$val + 1 -%] <br/>
[%- END -%] <br/>
```

If we initialize `groups.$val` before using it in the expression, there is no warning. 
**I did not get the issue when I used template-toolkit version 2.15.
Not sure what changed in 2.29 (or in any other version greater than 2.15) which is causing the warning?**

Comment: If you're using `-w`, you could try using `use warnings;` instead. Might not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a warning.

If you don't want to get the warnings, just populate the variable when assigning to it:

```
[%- groups.$val = (groups.$val || 0) + 1 -%]
```

or maybe

```
[%- groups.$val = (groups.$val.defined ? groups.$val : 0) + 1 -%]
```

Unfortunately, there's no operator similar to Perl's `++` or `+=` that would skip the warnings as the Perl's operators do.

Comment: Thanks @choroba.
I want to know what is changed between version 2.15 and 2.29 that this warning started to come. I did not see any warning when using version 2.15 of template-toolkit.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in the [Changes](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Template-Toolkit)...